# Why unknown type in generics with Java?

Tags: java, generics

This is Java code from ANLTR example.

```
public class SimpleLexer implements TokenSource {
    public static final int ID = 1; // Token.MIN_USER_TOKEN_TYPE;
    public static final int INT = 2;
    public static final int SEMI = 3;

    CharStream input;
    TokenFactory<?> factory = CommonTokenFactory.DEFAULT;
```

Why unknown type is used in this case? What's the difference when using `TokenFactory<Object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) and I think it answers your question quite well.

> Consider the problem of writing a routine that prints out all the
>   elements in a collection. Here's how you might write it in an older
>   version of the language (i.e., a pre-5.0 release):

```
void printCollection(Collection c) {
    Iterator i = c.iterator();
    for (k = 0; k < c.size(); k++) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
}
```

> And here is a naive attempt at writing it using generics (and the new
>   for loop syntax):

```
void printCollection(Collection<Object> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

> The problem is that this new version is much less useful than the old
>   one. Whereas the old code could be called with any kind of collection
>   as a parameter, the new code only takes Collection, which, as
>   we've just demonstrated, is not a supertype of all kinds of
>   collections!
>
> So what is the supertype of all kinds of collections? It's written
>   Collection (pronounced "collection of unknown"), that is, a
>   collection whose element type matches anything. It's called a wildcard
>   type for obvious reasons. We can write:

```
void printCollection(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

> and now, we can call it with any type of collection.